# Rebase a pull-request already merged in my local develop branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

upstream:

```
A -- B -- C | develop
```

I fork upstream and make a new branch (patch)

```
   P1       | patch
 /
C           | develop
```

I then submit a pull request.
Since upstream won't merge my PR quickly, I merge my patch branch on the local develop branch to start using my work.

```
   P1       | patch
 /    \
C  -- P2    | develop
```

Then upstream does some changes to develop:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

I do "git fetch upstream", now I have:

```
             P1       | patch
           /    \
A -- B -- C  -- P2    | develop
           \
            D -- E    | upstream/develop
```

And I want:

```
                       P1     | patch
                     /    \
A -- B -- C -- D -- E  -- P2  | develop
```

I tried to do a "git rebase -p upstream/develop" from develop which gives me exactly this history except for the name of the "patch" branch which gets lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved removing the last commit on my local develop branch (P2) with:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

In this way I can do a simple fast forward on the develop branch

```
git pull upstream develop
```

Now I can rebase my patch branch, and eventually redo the merge.

```
git checkout patch
git rebase upstream/develop

git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff patch
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, so I am waiting to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you created the pull-request against your `patch` branch, you can go with:

```
git checkout patch
git rebase upstream/develop
git push origin patch
```

This will update the pull-request with your new rebased patch.

*(assuming the pull-request is on github)*

Comment: This puts the patch branch in the correct state, but the local develop branch remains in a wrong state. Referring to the example I made in the question: P1 gets E as the parent commit, but P2 still has C as the parent. I'd like to either remove P2 (and redo the merge manually) or have git do it automatically for me, somehow.